Cypress PSoC1 assembly OR
I'm trying to write ad educational emulator of PSoC1 microcontroller.
Right now I'm testing the result of my preliminary coding and cross-checking it with microcontroller manual(s) to check if the emulator correctly execute the opcodes.
When I got into OR instruction I got a little confused by the manual description:

The Carry Flag is only changed when the OR F, expr instruction
is used. The Carry Flag will be set to the result of the logical OR of
the Carry Flag at the beginning of instruction execution and the
second argument’s value at bit position 2 (i.e., F[2] and
expr[2]). For the OR F, expr instruction the Zero Flag is handled the same
as the Carry Flag in that it is changed as a result of the logical OR
of the Zero Flag’s value at the beginning of instruction execution
and the value of the second arguments value at bit position 1 (i.e.,
F1 and expr1). However, for all other OR instructions the
Zero Flag will be set or cleared based on the result of the logical
OR operation. If the result of the OR is that all bits are zero, the
Zero Flag will be set, otherwise the Zero Flag is cleared.

(extracted from Cypress/Infineon PSoC1's Assembly Language User Guide pag. 61)
F register is of course the flags register of the microcontroller and thus it contains, among others, Carry (CF) and Zero (Z) flags.
To summarize, to me it sounds like this: if F is the target argument of the OR instruction, then OR acts on every bit, including CF and Z. If the target argument is NOT F, then neither CF nor Z are set, regardless of the result of the logical operation (unlike other instructions like ADD or SUB).
--- Correction after Jester comment
.... if F is the target argument of the OR instruction, then OR acts on every bit, including CF and Z. If the target argument is NOT F, then CF is not set, regardless of the result of the logical operation (unlike other instructions like ADD or SUB).
Is it right?
I know this is not a coding specific question, but in this case I think understanding the English part is more complicated than the coding itself (which can be trivial).

No, the text specifically says "for all other OR instructions the Zero Flag will be set or cleared based on the result of the logical OR operation"

correct...  but I still miss the need of a long and detailed description that could be almost completely skipped

I would simply say "unchanged" instead of "not set" to avoid confusion with clearing the carry (which is what some other architectures do for logical operations where carry makes no sense).
